# How to import NMF file into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, import

I just got my very first NMF file and I am stumped on how to get it into my database. I have been able to handle anything thrown at me so far using either QGIS and ogr2ogr to get my data into PostGIS.

It is a polygon layer, so just opening it in Excel is not enough and I do not have ArcGIS to run some extensions I heard may get the job done.

After Export to Excel, I can write some code to merge the related rows, make some WKT and construct some insert statements, but I would like to the extra work if possible.

Comment: Have you tried the QGIS DB Manager Import tool?

Comment: There is no NMF file type option. I tried anyway and I get an "Input layer missing or not valid"

Comment: Can you post a sample file type we can try out?